# no files created inside gen folder in newly created android sample project

Tags: android

I installed the ADT plugin in eclipse juno. Set up the SDK path. 
When i created the new Android sample app,  it is showing error. All the R.something is missing. Inside gen folder not files are created. Since it is sample project created by eclipse itself there is no error in xml resources. I am suspecting some android build steps are not running properly. In console no errors is shown.

Comment: you can check the accepted answer in the link.

Comment: The link helped me thank you so much